# Typescript - React/Redux to display table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, jestjs

I'd like to build a react typescript redux app to display a table using an api endpoint that was provided `https://example.com/users`

Develop a table with 4 columns Name, Email, City, and Company populating the rows with the response from the api endpoint.

I'm a noob, so bear with me.

1) I would need to use some sort of db to make a table yes? (i.e. mongoDb w/ mongoose)

2) `Redux/Redux-Thunk` is used to store state and be able to write action creators that return a function. Thunk can be used to delay a dispatched action or for conditionals.

Not sure what to use Redux for if we're just returning the data.

Same situation for needing to return the data in JSON format, what would be the use of Thunk in this case? (hw assignment)

Example of what needs to be returned:

**JSON**

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jane Doe",
  "username": "JD",
  "email": "jd@april.biz",
  "address": {
    "street": "Kulas Light",
    "suite": "Apt. 425",
    "city": "Dogville",
    "zipcode": "89143-3874",
    "geo": {
      "lat": "-37.3159",
      "lng": "81.1496"
    }
  },
  "phone": "1-555-555-8031 x55555",
  "website": "sample.org",
  "company": {
    "name": "Munder Difflin",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Hey, @mflow your question is about the functionality of things you can check those on any site like what redux do, what thunk does. If you have any query related to your need. you should send a minimal code, what you tried etc. then only we can help. This site is not for spoon feeding i guess.

Comment: Although using redux is not compulsory. You can go without redux and do things simply using states. thunk is a middleware. and of course you will need a db

Comment: gotcha, my assignment just requires me to use redux. I understand the middleware part and needing a db. But I'll revise the question with something when I figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: In simple words, redux is going to ease the availability of data in different parts of your apps. Using this you will be able to use your states as props and it will decrease the no of states.

Comment: you will have actions and reducers to perform the tasks.

Comment: does this matter if I'm using hooks? so no props, no class components stuff

Comment: no there is no issue if you are using hooks or not. Redux will improve the executability timings also.

Answer (score 0):

This question is extremely board and probably even unanswerable without someone actually completing your homework for you thus forgoing the learning process.

Setting up React/Redux/Typescript/Thunk as a Junior? goodluck.

If you're just taking data from an API and putting it in a table on the UI then there is no need to involve a database; also there is no need to involve redux or thunk for that matter those tools are more suited to people to sharing state globally across many components in larger applications.

But don't just take my word for it here are some words by the creator of React.
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

In terms of displaying the table; this is something i can help with below i have provided a codepen for generating the table required for your homework; use it as a guideline.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qzowyP?editors=1111

Purposely styled it and made it very minimal.

```
goodluck and hope this helps.
```

EDIT: If you're just taking data from a `external` api and displaying it there's no need to involve a database, if however you're hoping to create this API yourself, then obviously that changes things

Comment: Appreciate the answer, I believe I understand now that you cleared up a few things.

Comment: accept this as answer please so i can rake in the points if you don't mind